# React installation on mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, homebrew

i need some help because i recently start to work on my macbook (until my ubuntu VM) and i have some trouble with the installation.
And now when i load my old project i got this :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/gauloix/Documents/GitHub/BuyTheWay-FRONT/src/index.js: Unexpected token (10:0)
```

obviously i missed something during the pkg installation or something witch brew :/

If the error was to obvious dont blame me i've just finised my formation and i'm newbie ^^'

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZKw4.png)

Thanks beforehand !

Comment: Are you sure you installed all project's dependencies (especially `babel-preset-react`)?

Comment: yes i've installed ```babel-preset-react```  but during the installation i got : 

```npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3. ```

but duno how to update him :/

Comment: This is not an error, just a warning. I believe you can get rid of it with `npm install --save core-js@^3` (not 100% sure tho), but I also think this is just a warning, not an actual error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be error of babel library .
Try this "npm install -D babel-loader@latest @babel/core@latest @babel/preset-env@latest" installation . It might helpfull.

Comment: i've do it but same error :/ think i have totally missed my installation ....  or the problem come from my code maybe ? 

https://github.com/GauloixDev/BuyTheWay-BACK
https://github.com/GauloixDev/BuyTheWay-FRONT

Comment: btw github link you have sent is returning 404 error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for managing different Node.JS versions. Installing it is easy:

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

Once installed, you can install and use any Node.JS version with simple commands like:

```sh
# Install the latest Node.JS version
nvm install node

# Install a specific version
nvm install 6.14.4

# Use Node.JS version marked as "default"
nvm use node

# Or use some other version
nvm use node6
```

Once you have `nvm` ready, use `npx` to create a completely new React app and try to start it:

```sh
npx create-react-app myAppName
cd myAppName
npm start
```

If you don't get any errors during this process, I would suggest to simply overwrite newly created React app with your old code, **excluding `package.json`**. Before running the app with overwritten code, uninstall all packages you installed globally for the time being:

```sh
# List all globally installed packages
npm list -g -depth 0

# Use `npm uninstall` and uninstall them all:
npm uninstall whatever-globally
```

Finally, you will probably need to install some other dependencies (check your old `package.json`) manually:

```sh
npm install dep-1 dep-2 dep-3 ...
```

And then try to run the project with:

```
npm start
```

Comment: ty for help i will try this after a little break my mind need it ^^

Comment: Understandable ;)

Comment: i've just create the new folder with  ```create-react-app```  but after a Yarn start i got this ```The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0" ``` but when i ```npm webpack-v ``` i have the 6.14.5 one

Comment: Did you install Webpack globally beforehand (e.g. `npm install -g webpack`)? If so, can you try to remove it for now with `npm uninstall -g webpack` and try `npm start` again?

Comment: ok, after uninstall i get ```npm ERR= missing script: start``` when i npm start

Comment: Hm, it looks like you did some mistakes in your installation, I'll try to update my answer a bit more...

Comment: @GauloixDev I updated my answer, if this fails, I think we might need to move this to chat and solve it that way...

Comment: ty i will try this :)

Comment: when i try to launch ```nvm use node6``` i get ```N/A: version "node6 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install node6" to install it before using it.```  but when i nvm install node6  i get : ```gauloix@macbook-pro-de-gauloix ~ % nvm install node6
Version 'node6' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.```

Comment: Don’t use v6 if you don’t need it, current version is 13, so choose something closer to that number? :)

Comment: actually i have node v14.5.0

Comment: https://www.zupimages.net/up/20/28/utbm.png    HUMMMMMMMMM xD damn it's never easy with codding xD

Comment: Did you try to do suggested thing - add `.env` file in the root of the project and add content to it: `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`...